# String concatenation in a for loop

Tags: apex

Need help writing this piece of logic...

Address is a value object in my code. It has a set of variables with get;set;
I get list of Address and I need to iterate the list, get the variables out of the first object in the list and put in a string(var1+var2+...).. As a final output I need a concatenated string of string[0] + string [1] ....string[i] (i being the size of the list)..

For ex: my address object is

```
public Address() {
    public string street {get;set;}
    public string city{get;set;}
}
```

I have a list of address `Address[] addList = new List<Address>();` the size of the list is 3 in this example

Need to iterate the list and get object out of it.

```
for(Address a :addList) {
    String first object txt = a0.street+a0.city;
    String second object txt = a1.street+a1.city;
    String third object txt = a2.street+a2.city;
}

String finaltxt = first object txt + second object txt + third object txt.
```

Please help!

Regards,
P

Comment: Can you please update your question and provide some code snippets? By doing that you'll get a better answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming Address has a function `public override String toString()`, you don't need a loop at all:

```
String results = String.join(addressList, ',');
```

Edit:

I should have realized that `String.join` doesn't use toString(), so you do, indeed, need a loop:

```
String[] stringList = new String[0];
for(Address item: addressList) {
    stringList.add(String.valueOf(item));
}
String result = String.join(stringList, ', ');
```

Comment: Idea for `String.join` to use Object's `toString()`:   https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LjpUQAS

Answer (score 0):

```
String finaltxt='';
for(Address a :addList) {
    finaltxt+=a.street;
    finaltxt+=' ';
    finaltxt+=a.city;
    finaltxt+=',';
}
finaltxt=finaltxt.subString(0,finaltxt.length()-1);
```